# bootstrap navbar-toggler button is not working

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

i have manually downloaded and added the bootstrap library into my code and trying to click my bootstrap navbar-toggler button it is not working, but when i try to add the CDN Bootstrap Librabry it is working fine please somebody help me ho do i solve this issue for manual downloaded bootstrap library

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" >
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1">
        <title>Bootstrap Navbar</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="font_awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>

        <script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="node_modules/@popperjs/core/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light">
            <a href="" class="navbar-brand"><img src="img/logo/logo.png" width="150px" height="auto" style="border: 1px solid lightgrey; border-radius: 3px"></img></a>
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navber-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Menu 1</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <script></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are importing from `node_modules` ??

Comment: Please share proper instruction or your folder structure of your project.

Comment: You have to add @ before ```node_modules```

Comment: Check if there are any error messages on your browser's console.

Comment: in which node_module should i use @ or should i rename the folder starting with @

Comment: collapse.js:346 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert object to primitive value
    at RegExp.test (<anonymous>)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (collapse.js:346)
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at S.fn.init.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at S.fn.init.a._jQueryInterface [as collapse] (collapse.js:337)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (collapse.js:385)
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at S.fn.init.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (collapse.js:381)
    at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery.min.js:2)

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the jquery, proper & bootstrap js file at the end of the "body"

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8" >
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1">
            <title>Bootstrap Navbar</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="font_awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>



        </head>
        <body>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light">
                <a href="" class="navbar-brand"><img src="img/logo/logo.png" width="150px" height="auto" style="border: 1px solid lightgrey; border-radius: 3px"></img></a>
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navber-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Menu 1</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
<script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="node_modules/@popperjs/core/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
            <script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
            <script></script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

download files form here:

```
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css

https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js
```

put anywhere in your project (generally where  js's and css's are kept)
provide a path to them in html via script tag :

```
<script src='<absolutepath>/<file_name>'> </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Bootstrap 5 use this: `data-bs-toggle data-bs-target` and insert into the button HTML tag like so:

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggler" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
```